# How can I adjust the brightness on an HP Envy dv7?

Tags: 12.04, brightness

I have an HP ENVY dv7. When I was running Windows 8, I could tweak the brightness to my heart's content. Now, I'm limited to only the first five clicks on the brightness bar. After that, same max setting.

Is it possible to tweak the settings more?